# Implementation boundary-corrected wavelets on the unit interval

Tags: wavelet, software-implementation, reference-implementation

I was wondering if there is a 'ready-to-use' implementation available of the (boundary-corrected) wavelets constructed in
Cohen, Albert, Ingrid Daubechies, and Pierre Vial. *"Wavelets on the Interval and Fast Wavelet Transforms.”* Applied and Computational Harmonic Analysis 1, no. 1 (1993): 54–81. https://doi.org/10.1006/acha.1993.1005.
Specifically the ones defined in Section 4, on the unit interval $[0,1]$ (as opposed to $[0, \infty)$).

Any language or software would be okay, as would implementations of different wavelet families with similar properties.

Comment: Perhaps [BoundaryWavelets](https://github.com/JosefineAtMath/BoundaryWavelets)